# Writing with FILE pointer, reading with ifstream

Tags: c++, serialization, deserialization, ifstream

I have to handle with code where at one side information is written to a file using `FILE*` and on the other side it is read-in using `ifstream`.

I tried to compile a dummy code which shows the same behavior as the original code:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{

    FILE* outFile = fopen("testFile", "w");  
    char* posBuf = NULL;                                                       
    unsigned int counter = 0;                           

    posBuf = (char*) malloc( sizeof(int) + 2*sizeof(double) );

    int iDummy = 123;
    memcpy(posBuf+counter, (const void*) &iDummy, sizeof(int));          
    counter += sizeof(int);                           

    double dDummy = 456.78;
    memcpy(posBuf+counter, (const void*) &dDummy, sizeof(double));            

    counter += sizeof(double);
    dDummy = 111.222;
    memcpy(posBuf+counter, (const void*) &dDummy, sizeof(double));            

    fputs(posBuf, outFile);   
    fclose(outFile);          

    /////////////////////

    std::ifstream myfile; 
    myfile.open("testFile", std::ios::in|std::ios::binary);

    myfile.seekg (0, std::ios::end);                        
    unsigned int length = myfile.tellg();              
    myfile.seekg (0, std::ios::beg);                        

    char* posBuf2 = (char*) malloc( length );           
    myfile.read(posBuf2, length);                       

    counter = 0;
    int idummy = 0;
    memcpy((void*) &idummy, posBuf2+counter, sizeof(int));  
    counter += sizeof(int);                                       
    printf("read integer: %u\n", idummy);            

    double ddummy = 1.0;
    memcpy((void*) &ddummy, posBuf2+counter, sizeof(double));                 
    counter += sizeof(double);                                       
    printf("read double: %f\n", ddummy);                                      

    ddummy = 1.0;
    memcpy((void*) &ddummy, posBuf2+counter, sizeof(double));                 
    counter += sizeof(double);                                       
    printf("read double: %f\n", ddummy);                                      

    myfile.close();

    /////////////////////

    FILE* inFile = fopen("testFile", "r");
    char* posBuf3 = NULL;

    unsigned int c = 0;
    while ( ! feof (inFile) )
    {
        posBuf3 = (char*) realloc((void*) posBuf3, c+4);
        fgets(posBuf3+c, 4, inFile);
        c += 4;
    }

    idummy = 0;
    memcpy((void*) &idummy, posBuf, sizeof(int));
    printf("read again integer: %u\n", idummy);

    ddummy =1.0;
    memcpy((void*) &ddummy, posBuf+sizeof(int), sizeof(double));
    printf("read again double: %f\n", ddummy);

    ddummy =1.0;
    memcpy((void*) &ddummy, posBuf+sizeof(int)+sizeof(double), sizeof(double));
    printf("read again double: %f\n", ddummy);

    return 0;
}
```

The output I get from that is:

```
read integer: 123
read double: 0.000000
read double: 0.000000
read again integer: 123
read again double: 456.780000
read again double: 111.222000
```

As you can see, the deserialization only works if I use `FILE*` also for the reading of the file.

**QUESTION**: Any explanation for that behavior?

Thanks!

**UPDATED**:

1) open `ifstream` using `std::ios::in|std::ios::binary`

2) fix malloc

Comment: have you considered opening that stream with **`ios::in|ios::binary`** ?

Comment: Damn beat me to it @WhozCraig

Comment: @JasonLarke =P and I even highlighted =P

Comment: @WhozCraig: Thanks for the fast hint, but it doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: Have you tried writing a very simple program instead? Like 5 lines of code where you just write a string, close the `FILE*` and then open it as a stream and see if that works? Why are you trying to debug this in a complicated manner?

Comment: @WhozCraig: You answered (which you seemingly removed) was correct: `fwrite` instead of `fputs` solves the problem (nasty as all this is ;) ). If you put it as an answer you'll got the hook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few problems with the posted code:

- it is writing beyond the bounds of the memory allocated for `posBuf` (1 `int` and 2 `double`s are copied to the memory, but only `sizeof(int) + sizeof(double)` is allocated), which is undefined behaviour.
- [`fputs()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fputs) treats its argument as a null terminated string and so will stop writing when it encounters a null character. Open the file in binary mode and use [`fwrite()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fwrite) instead which does not treat its input as a null terminated string.

There are several other issues with the code;

- it is a horrible mix of C and C++
- avoidable explicit dynamic memory management (never mind `malloc()` and `realloc()`). Simply replaced with:

  ```
  char posBuf[sizeof(int) + 2 * sizeof(double)];
  ```
- `while (!feof(inFile))`.
- there is practically no checking of the success of I/O operations

Comment: `fwrite` instead of `fputs` did the job.